# Generating SVG font from multiple SVG graphics in Node.js

Tags: node.js, svg, icons

I'd like to create a Node.js app that allows users to combine a bunch of SVG icons into a custom web-font icon set. The only similar project I've found is [this site](http://fontspot.co.cc/) which looks interesting but is pretty buggy.

Eventually I'd like this app to also output all the various cross-browser font files and the CSS to use these icons on a page using best practices. So the overal goal is to create an SVG icon framework.

But the first thing I want to get working is combining multiple SVG icons into a SVG font file. Must be possible if the above mentioned site is doing it but I'm having trouble finding any good info.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Edit: I came across [this service](http://pictos.cc/server/) which looks very similar to my goal although I don't want to host the fonts and I'd like my service to be free (and possibly open-source as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many of my big ideas, someone thought of it first :)

For anyone who may come across this, check out [Keyamoon's font generator tool](http://keyamoon.com/icomoon/app/).

Comment: How 'bout an npm package to roll font files at build time?

Comment: @hurrymaplelad that would be awesome, especially if it generated a stylesheet to map the special characters to CSS classes.

Answer (score 5):

Kind of late, but if anyone else will need it, i think this will do: https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont

Answer (score 3):

If you want to automate things there is an NPM package called [`svg-font-create`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-font-create).

Answer (score 0):

Glyphter.com handles multi-path icons so that might be a good resource for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [svg-join](https://github.com/Climenty/svg-join) for combine multiple SVG in one symbol collection.

This tool create two files for you.
The first is "svg-bundle.svg":

```
<svg ...>
  <symbol id="svg1" ...>
  <symbol id="svg2" ...>
</svg>
```

Every symbol is your separate SVG file.

The last one is "svg-bundle.css":

```
.svg_svg1,
.svg_svg2 {
  width: 20px; // for example
  height: 20px;
}
```

Now you may use it in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="svg-bundle.css" />
...
<svg class="svg_svg1"><use xlink:href="svg-bundle.svg#svg1"></svg>
<svg class="svg_svg2"><use xlink:href="svg-bundle.svg#svg2"></svg>
```